# How to Handle ASP.NET post method using android?

Tags: android, asp.net

I am using android to call asp.net method. I have used HTTPClient to call this api but didnt get expected output. Is there any other method to call this api, please help me.

URL :
    http://xxx.yyy.com.np/pay.aspx

example posting data:

```
<form action="http://xxx.yyy.com.np/pay.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="2001" name="ID">
    <input type="hidden" value="user_name" name="Username">
</form>
```

source code:

```
 private void postDetailToServer() {
    try {

        // url where the data will be posted
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://xxx.yyy.com.np/pay.aspx";
        Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

        // HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        // add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", "111"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username","name"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseStr);

        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that Android Studio is an IDE, not a language. Also you aren’t shown any code relating to Android so it’s impossible to say what’s wrong.

Comment: thank you sir for your advice. and i've added the source code.

Comment: Hope you know HttpClient is depricated from Android 5.0. You should not use this methods. It might cause some issue with latest android versions. You should also check with HttpUrlConnection (Or Volley or Retrofit). Did you tried with POSTMAN? What issue you are getting in api response?

Comment: POSTMAN also gives the same response.